# Static nested sub-classes of the enclosing type can still refer to the private field members, why?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I found something which is ambiguous IMHO. Lets say we have the following class structure:

```
public class A
{
    private int privateVar = 1;
    protected int protectedVar = 2;

    static class B extends A
    {
        public int getPrivateVariable()
        {
            return privateVar; //error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field memberVariable
        }

        public int getProtectedVariable()
        {
            return protectedVar; //OK: Why?
        }

        public int getPrivateUnfair()
        {
            return super.privateVar; //Why this can be accessed using super which the protected member doesn't require.
        }
    }
}
```

1. Why at all does the static nested class has free access to the *instance* members?
2. Why there is a difference in the way `protected` and `private` variables can be accessed? This however, is not the case if the nested class is non-static inner class?

### EDIT:

3. Why is the private member of the enclosing type allowed to be accessed by the keyword `super`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Why do we require an explicit super for private variables?

Comment: "Because private fields aren't inherited".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Why at all does the static nested class has free access to the instance members?

Because `B extends A`. You're not accessing the member variables of `A`, you're accessing the inherited member variables of `B`.

> 2. Why there is a difference in the way protected and private variables can be accessed? This however, is not the case if the nested class is non-static inner class?

Because private fields aren't inherited, whereas protected fields are; but the private fields are still present in the superclass, and visible via `super` because `B` is nested inside `A`. Visibility modifiers aren't sufficiently expressive to articulate the same thing as accessing via super.

Comment: Then why don't the non-static inner classes require the super keyword?

Comment: Because if `B` were non-static, then `return privateVar;` is effectively the same as `return this$0.privateVar;`, i.e. it uses the hidden reference to the containing instance to access it. There is no such enclosing instance if the nested class is static.

Comment: Well. I get your point here. But is there any specific reason for this has been allowed via `super`. This could still be possible the way it is for normal inherited classes, by the use of accessor methods.

Comment: Visibility modifiers aren't sufficiently expressive to articulate the same thing as accessing via super. Any method you provide would necessarily be accessible outside the compilation unit (unless you use `private`, and then you're using `super` to call that too).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html 
`Note: A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.`
I think this is the source of confusion.

Comment: @mies Right.. I also went through this line and asked myself - why instance fields of enclosing class?

Answer (score 3):

> Why at all does the static nested class has free access to the instance members?

Nested classes have access to all private members in the same outer class. They are all compiled at once and accessor methods are added to allow this. Note: hte JVM doesn't allow such access which is why accessor methods need to be added.

> Why there is a difference in the way protected and private variables can be accessed?

protected members are assumed to be accessed via the super class as they are inherited. Private fields are not inherited, but can be accessed for nested classes.